# CSV to XML Using Client-Side Scripting

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, csv

I'm looking to write a small website that will convert a csv file to xml. I know of easy ways to do this with PHP, however I won't have a server to run it and something like XAMPP cannot be installed on the computer, so it needs to be something that doesn't need a server. Is there any code available to do that already? Maybe a jquery plugin?

Comment: First thing you're going to need is the HTML5 file access API.  You won't be able to support this on older browsers (like IE before 9). [Here is some documentation from Mozilla.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications)

Comment: Javascript cannot write to files, but you could copy and paste it's output into a text editor and save it.

Comment: Oh hey that's true - if you're not too picky you could allow the CSV to be pasted into a `<textarea>` and then convert it, to be cut/pasted out.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this library. It will convert CSV to JSON. From there, you can then create XML (or anything else for that matter)

https://github.com/archan937/csonv.js